# Can not switch editor tabs on double clicking different files

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I just created an editor(extending EditorPart) associated with a particular file extension i.e. **(.abc)**.

---

I added the components in createPartControl function. But there is a minor problem.

---

Suppose i create 2 files in same project with extension **.abc**, If i click `1.abc` it opens as 1st tab in editor, then if i click `2.abc` it opens as 2nd tab in editor. But when i again click `1.abc` it doesnt switch tab. I have to  right click `1.abc` then click **Open** to open `1.abc` file in editor. How to resolve this?

Comment: Single Click or Double Click? Single click won't change the selected editor.

Comment: Its Double click. But when I extend MultiPageEditorPart problem is resolved. Do i have to add a double click listener? If yes, how can i do it on files?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. This works for every editor I have tried.

Comment: Thanks,
I will try again with EditorPart